# TimeTravelingTriageTests

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, review-audits, triage

I received [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7858557) in Triage just now! It says that the question was asked today, just 6 minutes ago to boot'. The comments show that they were posted on April 13th, which was 14 days ago.

I guess it makes sense that the date of the audit question would be changed to today since it's TRIAGE where we review freshly baked questions. Shouldn't the date of the comments also be changed? Like they could say "5 mins ago", "4 mins ago", etc.

[image]

Comment: **You're paying attention!** This is a *good* thing.

Comment: "answers: 0; accepted: yes"

Comment: Hm, it now says: _"asked 14 days ago"_, when I open the audit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Oh, look - you noticed!

If you're paying enough attention to notice details like that, you can probably also read the question itself and pass the audit.